# Manage state of global variable react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

How do I get the state of this? I only need to put it as false and true the time I want at my components, but i`m doing something wrong, i know how do it when calling an API, but not like this.

I have this actions:

```
import { HIDE_MENU, ESTADO_MENU } from "./types";

export const hideMenu = dispatch => {
  return dispatch({
    type: HIDE_MENU
  });
};

export const estadoDoMenu = open => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: ESTADO_MENU
  });
};
```

and this reducer:

```
import { HIDE_MENU, ESTADO_MENU } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  open: true
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HIDE_MENU:
      return {
        ...state,
        open: false
      };
    case ESTADO_MENU:
      console.log("chega aqui");
      return {
        ...state
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

but calling it like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Estado do Menu: ", this.props.estadoDoMenu());
  }
```

I get `undefined` at the console, what is wrong?

Comment: How did you bind your estadoDoMenu function ??

Comment: do I need to bind it with redux?

Comment: @Matheus Ribeiro how are you accessing in component and post your combine reducer code

Comment: yes using `react-redux` mapDisptachToProps.

Comment: where do I put this?